# Pie chart not showing slice

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I create a pie chart using google services. the problem is that i want to show credit and debit in pie chart, but output comes only in one color. Here is my query.

```
$data = mysqli_query($link, "select SUM(pay_payable) as debit, SUM(pay_paid) as credit from purchasers_payment where p_id = '$pur_id'");
```

and here is my chart setting.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Debit', 'Credit'],
          <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
            {
                echo "['".$row['debit']."',".$row['credit']."],";
            }
            ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
```

here is mine code output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Pk4.png)

and i want output like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXwYR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for a `PieChart` uses rows for each slice
to get two slices, you need two rows of data...

```
['Label', 'Value'],
['Debit', 10000],
['Credit', 2000]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Debit', 10000],
    ['Credit', 2000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    is3D: true,
    height: 300
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

---

try the following php...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Label', 'Value'],
  <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
        echo "['Debit',".$row['debit']."],['Credit',".$row['credit']."],";
    }
  ?>
]);
```

Comment: Sir, definitely it helps me. Thank you so much for your response and that's the thing that i want.